# Windows 10 Function Keys Not Working

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I have A4TECH KL-7MUU keyboard. It's function keys (F1 to F12) do anything except their functioning.

- F1: Open This PC
- F2: Open New Tab in Browser
- F3: Close Browser
- F4: Open Default Browser
- F5: Open Calculator
- F6: Decrease Volume
- F7: Mute
- F8: Increase Volume
- F9: Pause Music
- F10: Stop Music
- F11: Previous Track
- F12: Next Track

Somehow all function keys bar turn into multimedia bar!!! The question is how to fix this issue??? Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a Fn or Function Lock key near your insert/home/pg up keys? Any driver software you can use to configure the keys? Is it this one? https://takas.lk/electronics-computers/computer-electronics-srilanka/keyboards/a4tech-kl-7muu-keyboard.html

Comment: @spikey_richie yes this is the exact model. As you can see in the keyboard image there is no FLock or anything like that.

Comment: Any driver software of applications to manage the key bindings?

Comment: what? can you be more specific?